# I am trying to play video file from document directory but its not playing in xcode6.2 with ios8.2

Tags: xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsdocumentdirectory, ios8.2

Hi i already working on MPMoviePlayerController but now i am facing issue in that, i thing that may be a version issue of xcode or ios

`NSString*theMoviePath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/9441426768774.mp4", [[AppDelegate appdelegate] getDocumentDirectoryPath]];
    AnandLog(@"theMovieURL :--->%@", theMoviePath);
    NSURL*theMovieURL=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:theMoviePath];
     self.moviePlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:theMovieURL];
     [self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(40, 197, 240, 160)];
     [self.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
     [self.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:NO];
    // And other options you can look through the documentation.
     [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];`

error

```
heMovieURL :--->/Users/ndot/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B147415A-F1F1-4576-972B-D1AE2C36993D/data/Containers/Data/Application/36777A8E-DE7D-4B7F-A74F-DF0835568C5D/Documents/9441426768774.mp4
```

2015-03-20 18:47:51.948 SampleConcepts[3266:86205] 18:47:51.948 ERROR:     98: Error '!obj' trying to fetch default input device's sample rate
2015-03-20 18:47:51.949 SampleConcepts[3266:86205] 18:47:51.949 ERROR:     100: Error getting audio input device sample rate: '!obj'
2015-03-20 18:47:51.949 SampleConcepts[3266:86205] 18:47:51.949 WARNING:   230: The input device is 0x0; '(null)'
2015-03-20 18:47:51.949 SampleConcepts[3266:86205] 18:47:51.949 WARNING:   234: The output device is 0x26; 'AppleHDAEngineOutput:1B,0,1,2:0'
2015-03-20 18:47:51.949 SampleConcepts[3266:86205] 18:47:51.949 ERROR:     404: error '!obj'
2015-03-20 18:47:51.949 SampleConcepts[3266:84774] 18:47:51.949 ERROR:     404: error -66680
2015-03-20 18:47:51.949 SampleConcepts[3266:86205] 18:47:51.949 ERROR:     113: * * * NULL AQIONode object
2015-03-20 18:47:51.950 SampleConcepts[3266:84774] 18:47:51.949 ERROR:     404: error -66680
2015-03-20 18:47:51.950 SampleConcepts[3266:86205] 18:47:51.950 ERROR:     703: Can't make UISound Renderer
2015-03-20 18:47:51.950 SampleConcepts[3266:84774] 18:47:51.950 ERROR:     404: error -66680
2015-03-20 18:47:51.950 SampleConcepts[3266:84774] 18:47:51.950 ERROR:     404: error -66680

My thought is problem problem may be in **xcode6.2 and ios8.2,** is anyone handle the scenario previously?

Guide me to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your code is correct. You can run a `MPMoviePlayerController` on `iOS8.1` and above use `XCode6.0.1` its working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks MR user2915020 i will try the same way